# how to add funtion to glyph icon plus and minus inbootstrap-3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using glyph icon-plus and minus in bootstrap on my web page.I want to add functionality to this two glyph-icons.
on clicking plus some panel must be added to the container and on clicking on glyph icon minus the individual panel must be removed.

how can I achieve this?i don't exactly know how to code in JAVA script,even new to J Query.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call the function like any other dom object

```
 <div class="container">
  <h2>Menu-up Glyph</h2>
  <p>Menu-up icon: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></p>


</div>
```

In js

```
 $(".glyphicon-plus").click(function(){
    alert("The paragraph was clicked.");
});
```

or other way

```
<p>Menu-up icon: <span onclick='alert("youClickedMe!");' class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example helps you .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Tab Pane add remove example</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <!-- Optional theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
 <div class="container">

  <h1>Tab pane exercise</h1>

 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
    <p>Plus icon button to add pane:
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm addPane">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Plus
     </button>
    </p>  
   </div> 
  
   <div class="col-lg-4">
     <p>Minus icon button to remove pane:
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm removePane">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> Minus
    </button>
     </p>
   </div>
   
  </div> 
  
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12" id="target">
   </div>
  </div>
 </div> <!-- /container --> 
  
 <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 <script language="javascript">
 
 var panel= $("<div id='myPanel' class='panel panel-default'><div class='panel-body'><p>ADD YOUR TEXT</p>");
 
 
 
 $(document).ready(function() {
 
   $(".addPane").click(function(){
    $("#target").append(panel);
   });
   
   $(".removePane").click(function(){
    $("#myPanel" ).remove();
   });
   
   
 
 });
 
 </script>
  </body>
</html>
```